# update ViewPart TableViewer

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-emf, emf

I have created this view:

```
public class MyView extends ViewPart {
    TableViewer tableViewer;

}
```

I have left almsot all of the implementation out, you need to know that there is amethod to get the table viewer.

The view has this presenter:

```
public class Presenter {
    ViewPart view;

    public void setView(ViewPart view) {
     this.view = view;
    }

    public void modelViewUpdate(List<Object> model) {
      //get the view
      //get the table
      //set the data
      //refresh
    }
}
```

what I am trying to do is update the model for the table given some list from another class...thing is, if I get the view, it returns a viewpart which I can't cast, so I can't get the table for the view and update the contents, is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: Why can't you cast the ViewPart? Your `MyView` is a `ViewPart`.

Comment: Sorry...let me put it this way...getView would return a viewpart in the presenter...I cant cast that to the view that it is binded to, if that makes sense

Comment: @greg-449 Sorry I have been able to...my bad